# Informing bosses that I finish my job in 10 hours / week

Tags: working-time, work-life-balance

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/93696/is-it-unethical-for-me-to-not-tell-my-employer-i-ve-automated-my-job?rq=1) made me think about my situation.

After different academic jobs, I took a tenure-track position that I can typically do in 10 hours/week. With the extra time I do hobbies or am with my family. It is not that the job is easy, it is more that the job exactly matches my skills, and that my weaknesses do not affect my performance. My colleagues, as most faculty, work at least 40hrs/week (many work more as explained [here](https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2014/04/09/research-shows-professors-work-long-hours-and-spend-much-day-meetings)). I am doing great and received many awards, so I am not worried at all about promotion. I also like the job.

**Should I inform my bosses how long it takes me to finish the job (10hrs/week)?** Please read the [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/93696/is-it-unethical-for-me-to-not-tell-my-employer-i-ve-automated-my-job?rq=1) I mentioned before answering. In that question, many people were very critical about finding ways of doing the job faster while not informing the boss.

**More information** (could add more if needed): I teach 3 classes per semester (about 7.5 hours total). For some reason it is very easy for me to just use the textbook, so I do not need to prepare my lectures (still receive good student evaluations). I have nearly 2.5 office hours per week, but virtually no student shows up, so I do research during that time. 2 hours/week have been enough to publish enough (research expectations are very low) and I am lucky enough that I have never had "writer's block" or anything like that. So far I have no service expectations. Compared to my colleagues I am publishing more, and in good journals (for a teaching institution). In the summer, I spend some time automatizing what I can. For example, I use software to automatically generate exams and the answers. I have graders, so I am equaling the "few" grading that I actually have to do to 10/hrs per week during the summer. At the end, it feels like working 10hrs/week year long (or a little more during regular semesters if you wish). Definitely far less than 40hrs/week.

I know that my service expectations will increase later, but it feels they would never reach 40hrs/week.

Comment: Fine that you can do your teaching and bureaucracy etc. in 10 hours per week. Aren't you expected to do research?

Comment: From our [help] you should avoid *asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”*

Comment: @Karl So far I can do the (not heavy) expected research within the 10 hours.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are expected to do in your position (research, teaching, administration etc)? If you teach; how much and how many classes? The question is hard to answer otherwise.

Comment: I am really confused by this question. What do you mean you "finish the job" in X hours per week? Academic job are such that there is always something more to do, typically on multiple fronts. In fact, 24 hours per day are not nearly enough to do the things I would like to do in a single day.

Comment: You don't have to write grant proposals, supervise grad students etc.? Don't tell us you do that plus teaching plus your own research in 10 hours!

Comment: I am definitely rounding, but so far it feels like, say, 13hrs/week during regular semesters and 0 hrs/week during the summer. So equivalent to 10hrs/week year long.

Comment: @101010111100, I admit that I could more research. However, I prefer to spend time with my family than publishing another paper. My classes are in the morning, so I basically arrive at 8 and leave at about 11 (no work in the summer).

Comment: This post smells like a troll. 3 courses a semester is roughly 9 hours of *just classroom time*. That's not what teaching any meaningful course is like. In a comment "So far I can do the (not heavy) expected research within the 10 hours." - This sounds like someone who has never been in academia and doesn't understand what "research" means for a professor.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I believe it is not a serious post.

Comment: @BryanKrause, you may be right about the trolling. I myself didn't want to be tooooo hasty to judge (thinking that maybe some peoples' situations did indeed exactly click with their natural capacities), but, well, I've never known of any case of this situation... apart from people deluding themselves that they're adequately doing their jobs.

Comment: I am not trying to troll. Just like in the link I posted shows how someone can do 40 hrs of work in just 2 hours, the same can happen in other areas. I do agree with one of the comments that the amount of research required in my department is "a joke". Also, as I said before, I am not currently required to do any service (or mentoring).

Comment: Whether this is a troll answer, I don't know, but this is not as strange to me as many are saying. I know a handful of tenured professors from my undergrad institution that taught the required 8h/week and went home. They weren't required to do administrative or supervising work. This is not at all uncommon outside of the Top 100 schools.

Comment: Great that you can enough research to get published in 2h/week (I feel like you could write a bestseller on how you do that.), but as you are in tenure-track/academia, why don't you do **more** research if you have time left?

Comment: @skymningen "why don't you do more research if you have time left" I did it in the past (was VERY research active), but still could not get tenure-track research positions (by the way, I have ASD and do **horribly** in interviews). So, after several years of doing research and no (permanent) research job, I decided to take a permanent position for which I was "overqualified" (easy teaching and minimal research).

Comment: I am really curious about a teaching centered institute where the teaching load is so small. Assuming that op is not a troll: have you ever though about to actually shooting higher than the bare minimum?

Answer (score 8):

It all depends on your contract and your professionalism. If you are hired to work the regular 40 hours/week, then you are obviously cheating really badly.

If you really have no working hours but work based on getting a few tasks done, it's really up to you and your professionalism. If you consider "your job done" by giving the students a textbook and using automated software for the exam and publishing the absolutely bare minimum required... and you spend the other 30 doing your things, well... it's up to your ethics and professionalism to know if your salary and position are justified or that job is, no offence, a joke.

Comment: No offence taken. I actually think that the research required in my department is a joke.

Comment: Is there anyone in your department that keeps you from doing more research than "required"? And are you sure that just keeping up with the bare requirements will be enough to stay competitive?

Answer (score 3):

It's both a strength and a weakness of academia that it runs on people doing a lot of things they aren't strictly required to do.  It means that we have a lot of leeway to carve out our own things we want to do, but it also means we all know some people who are scraping by doing the bare minimum.

I don't see what the point of telling anyone that you feel like you can complete your responsibilities in a very short period of time; I don't see what you would expect to come out of such a conversation.

I would think a bit about whether there are other things that are important to you that you could put your time toward.  Are there students at your school looking for research projects?  Are there other mentoring opportunities you could provide outside the college?  Are you completely happy with the way everything runs in your department or university?  Is there a class you could develop that your students might need?  Do you not have any research projects interesting enough to spend a few more hours on a week?  Is there no conference on any subject you would like to see happen?

I suspect if you look around you will see productive things out there that need doing; perhaps you should do some of them.

Comment: Exactly. It is not quite defensible to take up an "I've got mine, Jack (and screw you)" attitude in _any_ situation, much less academe. The question oughtn't be what one can "get away with", but something else, e.g., "what I have the capacity to contribute". Let's not model ourselves on vulture/venture capitalists.

Comment: I am not currently required to do any service (or mentoring). So I only have to teach and do minimal research. I might start to contribute in other ways before my contract requires me to.

Comment: @carl You can't really require people to do mentoring.  Most of us do it anyway.  I don't know about other fields or your university, but usually there are programs outside your department you can sign up for (such as: https://sites.google.com/site/awmmath/programs/mentor-network).